# How capture a custom work item type of Bug Category trough Test and Feedback extension?

Tags: tfs, azure-devops, azure-devops-extensions, azure-devops-server-2019

I'm unsing Azure DevOps Server 2020 on premises and a custom xml process model.
I created a custom work item type named "Defect" in Bug Category.

Now I'd like to capture a "Defect" using test tools:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/boards/backlogs/manage-bugs?view=azure-devops-2020&tabs=new-web-form#capture-bugs-using-test-tools, in particular I'm using the Test and Feedback extension https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/test/connected-mode-exploratory-testing?view=azure-devops-2020#create-bugs-or-tasks but I'd like to know how capture "Defect" with test runner too.

How is it possibile to configure test tools in order to capture the Defect custom work item type as well as the default Bug work item type?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, it's not able to create a custom work item type in Test & Feedback extension. Create issues, tasks, and feedback response work items is integrated in the extension, we are not able to change this.

You need to manually create Defect work item type, or create Bug/Task work item in the Test & Feedback extension.

Comment: Is there the same problem with the inherited process template ?

Comment: It is not related to which process template you use, but the extension doesn't support creating a custom work item, and we are not able to modify the extension.